# Buttons on bootstrap timepicker is not showing

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I'm using a time picker but I can't get to make the buttons show. Here's how the timepicker looks.

[image]

Here's how I render it.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control timepicker appt_time" style="width:200px;">

<script>
$('.timepicker').timepicker();
</script>
```

Here's how I set them in my header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/content/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/content/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/content/css/bootstrap-timepicker.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/script/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/script/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/script/bootstrap-timepicker.js"></script>
```

I got the css files and the js files for the timepicker
[Here](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/).

Any ideas what's causing this? Thanks!

Comment: are you referring to the input-append button?

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got css and js files but you've missed to capture the glyphicons.

The glyphicons are responsible for showing the buttons on the timepicker.

If you can inspect your developer tools on your buttons you can see that the images seems to be missing.

Here is what i've found on the site that you have picked timepicker

[image]

Include the glyphicons png file on your site to get the images work perfect.

Hope this helps

Comment: I see. That's what I'm expecting too. Can't seem to locate the image folder that contains the icons.

Comment: Hmm.. Here is the link that hosted the glypicons -> http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/img/glyphicons-halflings.png

Comment: I override the js file and changed the icons to my desired glyphicons. Thanks for the detailed explanation. Cheers!

Comment: Anyone of you help with how to add this icon without touching npm package?

Answer (score 0):

Try script as...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[id$='timepicker']").timepicker({
        minuteStep: 5,
        showInputs: false,
        disableFocus: true
    });        
</script>
```

Give an id , say id="timpick" and in call as $('#timpick').timepicker(options);

Comment: I'm setting it as a class since I will be using it to a lot of input box.