# Timepicker with bootstrap

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I need to create a timepicker not a datepicker !
I tried to download libraries but it seems nothing changed 
also my textbox wich I need to change it to a timepicker has no ID so, I need to fire event with class 
my experiment is

```
TextBox control = new TextBox { ID = _TimeFieldID + item.BlueprintFieldId, CausesValidation = true, EnableViewState = true, CssClass = "form-control timepicker margin-top-none metadatacontrol", Width = new Unit(ctrWidth + "%") };
```

in c# 
and I just need to assign css clas here 
but when I downloaded libs I can't get class name

and when I put this code

```
$(".timepicker").timepicker();
```

in document.ready it damaged the design of another element 
please help

Comment: brief what you tried so far

Comment: I tried to do as 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233638/buttons-on-bootstrap-timepicker-is-not-showing?rq=1

Comment: but I can't add any other controls except this textbox

Comment: but I need to do this http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/forms_inputs/view/timepicker.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use this jquery library for time selecthttp://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/158761)

Comment: I need to do it with bootstrap libs , also I still have the id problem